# direct object or indirect object?

Tags: grammar

**I want him to go.** In this sentence '' him '' is a direct object. who do i want ? him ''to go '' is object complement.

**I told him to go**  '' him '' in this sentence direct or indirect object ? I am really confused. I would be very happy if you could explain it in a few sentences.

Comment: Neither of your examples contains an indirect object or an object complement. Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

> *I want/told him* [*to go*].

This is called a catenative construction.

"Him" is the syntactic object of "want/told" and the *understood* (semantic) subject of the subordinate infinitival clause "to go" functioning as catenative complement of "want/told".

There is no indirect object or object complement.

Note that clauses do not function as objects, direct or indirect.

Comment: I'm deeply uncertain about this.  Can you provide a source that supports it?  I was under the impression that chain verbs / concatenations always function intransitively (compare:   "I prefer to stay.")

Comment: To be more specific, you're claiming that if you add a pp ('to go') to the end of a valid simple SVO ("I told him."), in some cases the object is no longer an object of the verb.   I'm looking for an example from a grammar text like this (and not like "I prefer to stay").  What is the function of the word "him", (syntax, since you are making the distinction...)

Comment: @BadZen RE your 1st comment: In complex catenatives with a _to_ infinitival clause as complement, the intervening NP **always** belongs syntactically in the matrix as object. The complement clause is not an object. RE your 2nd comment: What do you mean by PP? "To go" is an infinitival clause. In "I told him", "him" is object of "told". Similarly, in "I told him to go", "him" is object of "told". I recommend _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_  (Huddleston & Pullum) 2005 as a good reference book.

Comment: I'm not persuaded.   Exactly one author that I've found distinguishes "syntactic object" in this way and zero grammar texts 
(including this one)  I've found do.   This answer is somewhat weird and certainly confusing to learners.

Comment: @BadZen Did you downvote my answer?